# What do the 'X', 'I', 'II', etc. options on the main menu do?

Tags: natural-selection-2

On the main menu there are a series of buttons just above "Play" with rather inscrutable labels:

[image: Screenshot]

("Adversity" is my Steam profile name)

They light up when I hover over them as if to indicate they are clickable, but none of them do anything.

What the heck are these for?

Comment: Oh is it out? I used to love NS v1.04! Adversity implies its something to do with difficulty?

Comment: I think Adversity might be the profile name through steam but I agree it might be a difficulty setting, or possibly game mode type?

Comment: @Nick: It's actually been available for preorder for over a year.  Anyone who preordered it before today gets [a free copy for a friend](http://www.unknownworlds.com/ns2/news/2012/9/natural_selection_2_pre_orders_on_steam) :D

Comment: Looks like a menu with invalid options to me. Perhaps different game modes and/or different difficulties that are unlocked as you play through them?

Comment: I don't think there will be ever unlockables in NS; and game modes are selected by selecting the server (no lobby system). I guess they are a kind of badges; the first looks like a frontierman icon, the second one like a Kharaa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a secret treasure map to a [pot of gold](http://www.unknownworlds.com/ns2/forums/index.php?showtopic=118840&view=findpost&p=1942628)!

Actually, they are intended to be achievement flair badges, like special icons on a forum, but don't currently do anything.

Comment: They were also removed shortly before the game launched, probably for that exact reason. :)

Comment: Yeah, I was just going through the ns2 tag, didn't even look at question date :)